# how to generate multiple uuid and md5 files in golang

Tags: go, uuid, md5-file

Hi I've generated Md5 and uuid in golang but now I want generate it for multiple files using command line arguments, so what exactly I've to do. This is how I've generated my md5 and uuid:

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/rand"
        "crypto/md5"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "os"
        "log"
        "text/template"
       )

type Data struct {
    Uuid string
    Md5  string
}

func main() {

    uuid, err := newUUID()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
        }

    fmt.Printf("UUID:   %s\n", uuid)

        md5 := Getmd5(uuid)

        fmt.Printf("Checksum:   %s\n",md5)

        fillData := Data{uuid, md5}
    file, err := os.Create("text.txt")
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            defer file.Close()

    templ, err := template.ParseFiles("template.html")
        if err !=nil{
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    err = templ.Execute(file,fillData)
        if err != nil{
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
}

// newUUID generates a random UUID according to RFC 4122
func newUUID() (string, error) {
uuid := make([]byte, 16)
          n, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, uuid)
          if n != len(uuid) || err != nil {
              return "", err
          }
      // variant bits
      uuid[8] = uuid[8]&^0xc0 | 0x80
          // version 4 (pseudo-random)
          uuid[6] = uuid[6]&^0xf0 | 0x40
          return fmt.Sprintf("%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", uuid[0:4], uuid[4:6], uuid[6:8], uuid[8:10], uuid[10:]), nil
}

func Getmd5(uuid string) (string) {
data := []byte(uuid)
          //md5_buffer := fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5.Sum(data))
          md5_buffer := md5.Sum(data)
          return fmt.Sprintf("{0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x};\n",md5_buffer[0:1],
                  md5_buffer[1:2],md5_buffer[2:3],md5_buffer[3:4],md5_buffer[4:5],md5_buffer[5:6],md5_buffer[6:7],md5_buffer[7:8],
                  md5_buffer[8:9],md5_buffer[9:10],md5_buffer[10:11],md5_buffer[11:12],md5_buffer[12:13],md5_buffer[13:14],md5_buffer[14:15],
                  md5_buffer[15:16])

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you show some code and what you have tried already?

Comment: Can you be clear on what exactly do you mean . Are you asking how to accept command line arguements in golang ?

Comment: Yes @Sarathsp how to acept command line arguments in golang

Comment: @ShriramKatneshwarkar I have answered how to accept command line arguements in golang

Comment: @ShriramKatneshwarkar what exactly are you trying to write to multiple files? What do you want to read from command line arguments?

Comment: The code looks messy. Please run `gofmt` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.Args` to accept command line arguements

`os.Args` provides access to raw command-line arguments. Note that the first value in this slice is the path to the program, and `os.Args[1:]` holds the arguments to the program.

Your program will look like this, have a look at `createFile` and  `getNumberOfFiles` functions and the `main`

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "crypto/rand"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "text/template"
)

type Data struct {
    Uuid string
    Md5  string
}

func createFile(uuid string) {
    md5 := Getmd5(uuid)
    fmt.Printf("Checksum:   %s\n", md5)
    fillData := Data{uuid, md5}
    file, err := os.Create(uuid + ".txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    templ, err := template.ParseFiles("template.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    err = templ.Execute(file, fillData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func getNumberOfFiles() (num int, err error) {
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        return 0, errors.New("Not enough arguements")
    }
    if num, err = strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1]); err != nil {
        return
    }
    return num, nil
}

func main() {
    numberOfFiles, err := getNumberOfFiles()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("Creating %d files", numberOfFiles)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++ {
        uuid, err := newUUID()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
        }
        createFile(uuid)
    }
}

// newUUID generates a random UUID according to RFC 4122
func newUUID() (string, error) {
    uuid := make([]byte, 16)
    n, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, uuid)
    if n != len(uuid) || err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // variant bits
    uuid[8] = uuid[8]&^0xc0 | 0x80
    // version 4 (pseudo-random)
    uuid[6] = uuid[6]&^0xf0 | 0x40
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", uuid[0:4], uuid[4:6], uuid[6:8], uuid[8:10], uuid[10:]), nil
}

func Getmd5(uuid string) string {
    data := []byte(uuid)
    //md5_buffer := fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5.Sum(data))
    md5_buffer := md5.Sum(data)
    return fmt.Sprintf("{0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x,0x%x};\n", md5_buffer[0:1],
        md5_buffer[1:2], md5_buffer[2:3], md5_buffer[3:4], md5_buffer[4:5], md5_buffer[5:6], md5_buffer[6:7], md5_buffer[7:8],
        md5_buffer[8:9], md5_buffer[9:10], md5_buffer[10:11], md5_buffer[11:12], md5_buffer[12:13], md5_buffer[13:14], md5_buffer[14:15],
        md5_buffer[15:16])

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sarathsp this clears the idea how to use command line argument but how it will be helpful to generate multiple file.?

Comment: I am not clear about multiple file ? Now you can run the script for any files and get md5 sum of the file. Is it not what you need ? If not what exactly do you need ?

Comment: actually when run my script it will create one file and in that it will generate md5 and uuid, and now I've to generate multiple files to generate multiple md5 and uuid. Means when I give command line argument as e.g. 5 then is should create 5 files with all different md5 and uuid.

Comment: @ShriramKatneshwarkar  All what you need to change would be copy all your code from the `main` as given in the question to a new function that accept a file name . In the main you will have a for loop that loops n times as the arguement and you may create `UUID` there and pass it to the function which whill now create files with file name as the uuid and will conatain your desired data

Comment: @ShriramKatneshwarkar updated  the answer with your code updated for your needs. Please accept the answer if this helped you

Comment: @ShriramKatneshwarkar good to know, please upvote the answer if it helped you :D